# How to fix "File.exists()" wrong Boolean return?

Tags: java, server, client, file-handling

I currently have a basic client-server application to develop as my assignment.

The program is just about calculating prime numbers, the GCD etc.
The client-side is a GUI and the Server-side (localhost) is responsible for executing the calculations and sending the results back to the client.

One of the requirements is that when the user at the client-side clicks the "Calculate" button, the client program sends the Class Name of the particular task (`ComputePrime.java`, `ComputeGCD.java`, etc) that the client needs the server to execute and calculate. Then the server needs to check if the class file exists in the folder. If it doesn't, then the server sends an error message to the client. If it does exist, then the calculation should be carried on as expected.

However, for some reason "the File.exists()" instruction keeps returning false even if the file exists. Also, I need this to work during runtime as well. For example, If I delete a `ComputePrime.java` after the program is executed, it should return false and if I add it back at runtime, it should return true.

I put it a thread because that runs infinitely just to see if it would work for dynamic removal and addition if the file. Any other ideas are welcome as long as it's basic java code.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread()
{
@Override
public void run()
{
    File file = new File("../Contract/ComputePrime.java");
    if(file.exists())
    {
        System.out.println("Exists");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Not Exists");
    }
    try {
        this.sleep(1000);
        this.run();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex){}

}
};
t1.start();
```

P.S this code is at the server-side.

Here is the [Project folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM1rA.png).

I've tried using different relative path techniques such as ".././Contract/ComputePrime.java" , ".././ComputePrime.java" , "~/Contract/ComputePrime.java", "../Contract/Compute" and "./../Contract/ComoutePrime.java". They all return false even if the file is in the folder. It has to be a relative path so the program works on my professor's computer.

I'm not sure why it's behaving like this. I've been googling for the past 5 or 6 hours trying to fix this and I got nothing that's why I'm asking a duplicate question.

Finally if a solution is found, is it possible that it would at runtime/dynamically?. For example, if I delete the file after execution, it should return false and when I put back the file, it should return true.

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE** 
After trying file.getAbsolutePath, [this is what I get as the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO46F.png)

So, I'm guessing my relative path in the code above is correct then?

Comment: what do you mean "how to fix"? that method works just fine. debug your code, and check the entire path of the file you are testing

Comment: I did check the path and it's correct.  I'm not sure why it's returning false regardless.

Comment: Switch to `java.nio` and try again…

Comment: You are using relative paths. Make sure you know which directory is the current one at all times. And `~` will never work, that's a shell thing. Use the java system property `user.home` instead.

Comment: Okay will try that those right now.

Comment: In doubt print out `file.getAbsolutePath()` and compare it with where the files is at.

Comment: If I execute ComputeServer.java, what would the relative path to ComputePrime.java be? I seem to be getting it wrong I guess.

Comment: Unrelated: dont use recursion like this. Use a **loop** instead. Theoretically, you risk a stackoverflow exception. You have no idea how often this method will be called. (this is not a problem here, because you have that 1 second delay, which means that you only get 86000 recursive calls .. per day).

Comment: *Why* are you using this method? Surely the server is ultimately going to compile or execute or open this file? In which case you should just attempt the operation and catch the error if and when it really happens. Existence has to get checked internally at that point anyway. All you're doing here is doubling the work, and introducing a second point of failure.

Comment: That depends on how you execute it. If you run it on the command line with `java ...` it's relative to your current directory. If you run it through an IDE, the IDE sets a current directory for the process. You can check the system property `user.dir` to see the current working directory for the process.

Comment: @GhostCat I'll bear that in mind. I think i'll change it so that the server only checks when the client sends a request. But first I need this File.exists() to work dynamically at runtime too

Comment: @user207421 I need at the client side to show an error whenever the server checks if the file is present in the folder. I managed to get it working somewhat at least before. Like if before execution, the server throws the error if the requested file is not there, but I add the file back without restarting the client and the server, the server still says it's not there

Comment: It looks like `Assignment1`is your current directory. The correct relative path would then be `./src/Server/Contract/ComputePrime.java`

Comment: @RogerGustavsson I'm sorry but I'm not sure how to compile multiple java files in different folders on cmd. If it's not too much to ask, could you show me how to get this working on netbeans?

Comment: @RogerGustavsson Oh sweet Jesus, you're Godsend.  It's working!!!! I'm so happy omg. After so many hours ;-;.

Comment: Good. But read the comment by @user207421, you are probably doing things in the wrong way to begin with. At least you know how to find the file relative your current directory now.

Comment: @RogerGustavsson yes he/she is right. But i need the server to load the class file once I put back the file in the folder at runtime. Hence, the checking. I've removed the thread. It was just a testing thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my relative path was wrong. 
The answer as provided by @RogerGustavsson :

./src/Server/Contract/ComputePrime.java